# Getting SelectedValue from a DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, ascx

I am trying to create a basic macro that encapsulates a form and the ability to email the details entered into it. It works fine for Textboxes, but for some reason the DropDownLists take the first value in the list of options. I've been working on this for hours and seem to've tried everything, so hopefully someone can suggest a solution. I am using Umbraco 4.0.3 and unfortunately upgrade is not an option. My reduced code is as follows:

CorpRefundForm.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CorpRefundForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="umbracowebsitewizard_site.Usercontrols.CorpRefundForm" %>

<asp:DropDownList ID="frm_dropdown" runat="server" CssClass="linkselect" />

<br />

<button id="submitButton" runat="server" onserverclick="submitButton_Click">Submit</button>
```

CorpRefundForm.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace umbracowebsitewizard_site.Usercontrols
{
    public partial class CorpRefundForm : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select one", ""));
                frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "One"));
                frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "Two"));
                frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "Three"));
                frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Four", "Four"));
            }
        }

        public void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SmtpClient mySMTPClient = new SmtpClient();

            mySMTPClient.Send("[email removed]", "[email removed]", "Test", frm_dropdown.SelectedValue + frm_dropdown.Text + frm_dropdown.SelectedItem.Value + frm_dropdown.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

CorpRefundForm.ascx.designer.cs:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace umbracowebsitewizard_site.Usercontrols
{
    public partial class CorpRefundForm
    {
        protected DropDownList frm_dropdown;
    }
}
```

Comment: you only want to get the selected value right ? What is this frm_dropdown.SelectedValue + frm_dropdown.Text + frm_dropdown.SelectedItem.Value + frm_dropdown.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: That's me trying everything I could see to try and get the value from the DropDownList.

Comment: I have written your code, and everything work well!

Comment: Were you using Umbraco version 4.0.3?

Comment: Turns out I can get it to work if I take it out of the context of the rest of the page ... you might've helped me solve this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out the jquery.linkselect-1.2.07.min.js library was doing something with the DropDownList that broke it. Took that out and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens since your first `ListItem` does not have a `Value` assigned. Try to assign a value, and see if it works.

```
 frm_dropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select one", "-1"));
```

Comment: No luck. The email just contains the text "-1-1-1Select one".